# Changing Locale at runtime not effecting fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, locale

When user changes language i execute following code,it works fine for the present fragment in the activity, but if i go to other fragment, it partially updates the language, some strings gets updated and shows old language, and most importantly the date does not changes in inner fragments,and other activities.

I tested this in nougat, marshmallow and oreo, and its happening in all of OS.

When user changes the language i execute following.

```
 LocaleHelper.setLocale(getApplicationContext(), language);
 recreate();
```

**LocalHelper**

```
public static Context setLocale(Context context, String language) {
        persist(context, language);


        Log.d("LocaleSet", language);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return updateResources(context, language);
        }

        return updateResourcesLegacy(context, language);
    }
```

**Method for post marshmallow OS.**

```
   @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private static Context updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.setLocale(locale);

        return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
    }
```

**Pre Nougat**

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static Context updateResourcesLegacy(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            configuration.setLayoutDirection(locale);
        }

        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return context;
    }
```

In each activity, i execute following code.

```
@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base, LocaleHelper.getLanguage(base)));
}
```

**Mainfest**

```
<application
        android:name=".GlobalApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.homeactivity.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="locale"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.profilepageactivity.ProfilePageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_profile_page"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Comment: Can you also add your `AndroidManifest.xml` ?

Comment: @madlymad : i have updated the question and added manifest file, please check.

Comment: Have you tried this without the `android:configChanges="locale"` in the manifest?

Comment: @madlymad : just tried this, but no change

Comment: @madlymad : It looks like, its now working fine with strings, but date does not get changed

Comment: It may related with the way you format your dates

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern, new Locale("language")) , and its now loading date just fine.. Please add your solution as answer i will accept it. can you please also guide me how removing `android:configChanges` fixed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you are using [this](https://gunhansancar.com/change-language-programmatically-in-android/) approach. Where its not suggested any change in the `AndroidManifest.xml` so the `android:configChanges="locale"` may cause the misbehavior you defined.

For the date formating you should take into consideration that your application is not using the `Locale.getDefault()` but something different that is defined by the user and your `LocaleHelper` mechanism.

***Some extra details about config change***

The `android:configChanges` means you don't want the system to recreate your activity when one of the provided attribute happens. In your case the `locale`.

In terms of development with that approach in order to properly handle this option in the manifest you have to implement the

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  // refresh your views here
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

and then perform your own handling. Something that you didn't required in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Application class which extended in the manifest file.

```
package com.example.languageapplication;

import android.content.Context;

public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    private static Application applicationInstance;

    public static synchronized Application getInstance() {
        return applicationInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        applicationInstance = this;
    }

    public void initAppLanguage(Context context) {
        LocaleUtils.initialize(context, LocaleUtils.getSelectedLanguageId());
    }

}
```

Locale utils class for set language in shared preferences and update configuration for set language

```
public class LocaleUtils {

    public static final String ENGLISH = "en";
    public static final String FRENCH = "fr";
    public static final String SPANISH = "es";


    public static void initialize(Context context, @LocaleDef String defaultLanguage) {
        setLocale(context, defaultLanguage);
    }

    public static boolean setLocale(Context context, @LocaleDef String language) {
        return updateResources(context, language);
    }

    private static boolean updateResources(Context context, String language) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
        context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
        configuration.locale = locale;
        resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        return true;
    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    @StringDef({ENGLISH, FRENCH, SPANISH})
    public @interface LocaleDef {
        String[] SUPPORTED_LOCALES = {ENGLISH, FRENCH, SPANISH};
    }


    private static SharedPreferences getDefaultSharedPreference(Context context) {
        if (PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext()) != null)
            return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        else
            return null;
    }

    public static void setSelectedLanguageId(String id){
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getDefaultSharedPreference(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext());
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("app_language_id", id);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String getSelectedLanguageId(){
        return getDefaultSharedPreference(Application.getInstance().getApplicationContext())
                .getString("app_language_id", "en");
    }
}
```

set Language on click of a button in another activity and restart launcher activity

```
public class setLaunguageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    }

    public void setEnglish(View view) {
        LocaleUtils.setSelectedLanguageId("en");
        Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
        startActivity(i);

    }

    public void setFrance(View view) {
        LocaleUtils.setSelectedLanguageId("fr");
        Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

Initialize Application class in the main activity like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textInfo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Application.getInstance().initAppLanguage(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

this code is working for me